# Result of Stored Procedure save in table variable

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have question: I have stored procedure A(return three out paramters). I want to call procedure A in loop and insert these three parameters into temporaty table and return this table.

```
    DECLARE
    Type TestTable IS TABE OF NUMBER; -- for example one parameter!!!
    myTable TestTable;
BEGIN
LOOP
    A(o_param1, o_param2, o_param3);
    -- myTable insert o_param1,2,3;
    -- insert into myTable values(99); - here I have error PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
END LOOP;
SELECT * FROM myTable;
END;
```

I dont know how to do -- myTable insert o_param1,2,3;. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

write insert statement inside the loop. so for each loop you can have the values inserted to the table and give a commit after the loop.

But you cannot have a select * from table inside the anonymous block. Remove that from the block and after end; you can try running select * from table to see the output.

```
BEGIN
  LOOP
    A(o_param1, o_param2, o_param3);
    -- myTable insert o_param1,2,3;
     insert into myTable values (o_param1, o_param2, o_param3);
  END LOOP;
  commit;
  --SELECT * FROM myTable;-
  END;
  SELECT * FROM myTable;
> Blockquote
```

Comment: If myTabe is temporaty table created in current code?? Declare type .... , myTAble typeTable;

Comment: if it is a table type definition you have to assign the values to each column in that for example myTable(indx).o_param1 := o_param1 .... like that..

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot insert data into myTable directly (insert into myTable) because Oracle table types, declared in a declare section of the script, are not visible in sql statements (exception - insert using 'bulk collect' with types, declared in Oracle dictionary).
Even if you insert data in myTable using myTable(idx)...  you can not select it outside the script because myTable exists only inside the script.
I think the simpliest way is to create usual table or global temporary table. If you will use global temporary table create it with 'ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS' (if you use commit after insert)